Prophet forecast data doesn't match observed data
Context
I'm trying to model office attendance using the Prophet library in python. My data is pretty simple, headcounts at 15 minute intervals. It's shown by the black dots in the plot below.

The daily and weekly trends look spot on:

I've also included holidays.
The code looks like this:
m = Prophet(holidays=holidays, weekly_seasonality=True, growth="flat")  # "logistic")
p_df = sdf[["OCCUPANCY_AVG"]].reset_index()
p_df.columns = ["ds", "y"]
p_df["cap"] = 180
df["floor"] = 0
m.fit(p_df)

future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=24 * 60, freq="H")
future["cap"] = 180
future["floor"] = 0
# future.tail()

forecast = m.predict(future)
# forecast[["ds", "yhat", "yhat_lower", "yhat_upper"]].tail()

fig1 = m.plot(forecast, xlabel="Date", ylabel="Headcount", include_legend=True)
# %%
fig2 = m.plot_components(forecast)

Question
There are several things that I'm not thrilled about here:

The forecast data can't, in real life, go negative
The observed data peaks are much higher than even the uncertainty interval

How can I make the model respect that it's predicting a quantity that can't go negative, and also make it fit the input data?

Ben,
From my experience prophet doesn't work well with the data that has less than several years (by it's math design of). This can be seen from the model documentation where in all examples they try to predict multi-year trends and seasonality.
Back to your question. Your data is in positive domain (from zero to inf), however prophet uses linear model with normal distribution (which in theory is distributed from [-inf, inf]). In a lot of cases this doesn't effect model performance. But in your dataset there is a lot of zeros which models try to predict. And to do this it needs to shift mean of the normal distribution down by a lot and thus give a lot of negative values in predictions (and this also causes misprediction of the peaks). Basically this is the reason of mispredictions.
I would suggest to transform your data to better suit the prohet model definition. Try applying a log transformation on attendances: log(1 + cnt_attendances). Then model the log attendances. In theory this transformation should solve both your errors.
